# DSN8a10.emp is an undefined name

Tags: sql, db2

I just created a table named TELE by running the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE TELE
(NAME2 VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
NAME1 VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
PHONE CHAR(4));
```

Now, I am trying to populate it with data from the DSN8A10.EMP table, by running the following query:

```
INSERT INTO TELE
SELECT LASTNAME, FIRSTNME, PHONENO
FROM DSN8A10.EMP
WHERE WORKDEPT = 'D21';
```

But I get the following error:

> [42704][-204] "DSN8A10.EMP" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204,
>   SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.23.42.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA with com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver Data Server Driver.

Can you help me with a solution, please?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some possibilities:

- the table does not exist because you have a typo in the schema name or the table name
- the table does exist but in a different database
- the table exists in the database, but the name or schema has a MiXed case, in which case you must use double quotes around the schema name and table name. So "DSN8a10"."emp" is DIFFERENT from DSN8a10.EMP.

If the Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, this query may help to show a mixed case name. It's possible the table is a view or alias or nickname.

```
select tabschema, tabname from syscat.tables where upper(tabschema)='DSN8A10' and upper(tabname) = 'EMP'
```

If the Db2-server runs on i-Series:  use  QSYS2.SYSTABLES instead.

```
select table_schema, table_name from qsys2.systables where upper(table_schema)='DSN8A10' and table_name='EMP'
```

If the Db2-server runs on Z/OS: use SYSIBM.SYSTABLES instead:

```
select creator, name from sysibm.systables where upper(creator)='DSN8A10' and upper(name) = 'EMP'
```

Comment: Is there any way to see if that table exists in the current database? DSN8A10.EMP is a sample IBM DB2 table, it should be listed on the system tables, right?

Comment: It seems that the sample database with all the samples, including the EMP table, needed to be install as per instructions on https://www1.columbia.edu/sec/acis/db2/db2d0/db2d0241.htm#HDRSAMTBL.
Once completed, the tabschema is going to be set to your computer username, in which case to display the content of the table would be 

select * from <pc_username>.EMP;

Thank you so much @mao.